# Why does ReadProcessMemory have `lpNumberOfBytesRead`?

Tags: c++, windows

From [ReadProcessMemory in MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553.aspx)

**lpBaseAddress [in]**:
A pointer to the base address in the specified process from which to read. Before any data transfer occurs, the system verifies that all data in the base address and memory of the specified size is accessible for read access, and if it is not accessible the function fails.

**nSize [in]**:
The number of bytes to be read from the specified process.

**lpNumberOfBytesRead [out]**
A pointer to a variable that receives the number of bytes transferred into the specified buffer. If lpNumberOfBytesRead is NULL, the parameter is ignored.

So.. `ReadProcessMemory` can only completely succeed or completely fail. And the size is obviously known to the caller -- had to pass it in to make the call. Why have the `lpNumberOfBytesRead`?

Comment: That's a _damn_ good question.

Comment: Dark magic going on here. There's a specific error ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY which states "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed". This seems to fly in the face of "completely succeed or fail" but I have no idea which is right.

Comment: Here's a thought. Even though you can _read_ the entire buffer from the other process, what if you can't _write_ to the entire buffer in your current process? Clutching at straws, but plausible, I guess.

Comment: @pax: WriteProcessMemory's docs say much the same thing. My hypothesis is either 1. there's some special meaning of "accessible" here, or 2. the function "fails", but still copies as much data as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`winerror.h`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819773.aspx):

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY
//
// MessageText:
//
//  Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
//
#define ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY               299L
```

`ReadProcessMemory` would return FALSE and `GetLastError` would return `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` when the copy hits a page fault. This is a common scenario in dumpers, which have to work on a potentially corrupted process so they can't be sure if the requested area is valid or not (the pointer they chased to get the start address could be corrupted and point to la-la-land), but they would still like to copy as much as possible into the dump.

Comment: So you're saying ReadProcessMemory can fail but still copy some memory?

Comment: Yes. Imagine *how* would you implement a ReadProcessMemory that is atomic (either copies everything, or nothing). You would have to either *rollback* the copy (meaning you have saved previous content you wrote into) or you would have to do the copy in two passes (one validates each page in area requested, one copies) and hope the target process does not change a page protection in between the passes.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe in some previous API versions this function did not completely fail, but could return partial results. So the out parameter is kept for compatibility, but newer programs can pass a NULL and ignore it.

Comment: But this would mean someone following the docs now would have their programs randomly fail on older OSs.... I don't see that not at least being documented on MSDN...

Comment: @Billy ONeal: If you're using the version of the API documented on MSDN, your application will in all likelihood fail to run on those older operating systems anyway, because some of the API functions are just plain *missing* from older versions of the API. If you intend to develop for Windows 95, you should be basing your code on the Windows 95 documentation. If you're not developing for Windows 95, then the extra information is just noise.

Comment: @Anon: I was not aware ReadProcessMemory existed at all on Win95. Thought that was an NT only bit. (I don't care about anything but NT anyway...)

Comment: @Billy: I really have no idea either. Just pointing out that not documenting quirks of older systems in the main documentation is a reasonable position.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the area might be accessible in terms of permissions, but an error in a page fault might only allow part of it to be read. That's just a guess though.

Edit: See this page: [ReactOS - STATUS_PARTIAL_COPY](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/dfa/ntoskrnl_2mm_2ARM3_2virtual_8c_source.html)

```
> // Otherwise, we failed  probably during the move
```

It seems like any problem that's out of the control of the function might return this error code.

Answer (score 1):

There's an inherent race condition. Copies aren't instant. Sure, the function checks up front whether it's likely to succeed, but it is possible that the memory range becomes unmapped during the copy. It's another running process you're looking at, after all, quite likely unaware ofyour ongoing `ReadProcessMemory()`.

(Remus Rusanu also hinted at such a partial copy, but suggested a corrupted process as the root cause, not a race.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, aside from [9000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457171/why-does-readprocessmemory-have-lpnumberofbytesread/4457191#4457191) is that the parameter is there for future expansion purposes.  Perhaps at one point (and maybe even now) there were plans to provide ReadProcessMemory implementations that could partially fail so the out parameter was put there for that reason.  This would be a (not particularly good) way to avoid the whole API/APIEx/APIEx2/whatever problem that Win32's APIs have laboured under for years.