# Function ReadProcessMemory keeps returning ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

I know that there are other people that have asked this question but it seems as though none of them reached a satisfying or understandable conclusion. I can't use what isn't answered. I am not quite sure what the problem is and I have tried various different solutions with no success so here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, (DWORD)7312);

    if(hProc == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    HANDLE token;

    OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &token);

    void *baseAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 500, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if(baseAddr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "VirtualAllocEx has failed" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Base Address: " << baseAddr << "\n" << endl;
    }

    DWORD prevProt;

    if(VirtualProtectEx(hProc, &baseAddr, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &prevProt) == 0)
    {
        if(GetLastError() == 87)
        {
            cout << "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER\n" << endl;
        }
        else if(GetLastError() == 487)
        {
            cout << "ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS\n" << endl;
        }
    }

    void *buffer;

    if(ReadProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, &buffer, sizeof(SIZE_T), NULL) == 0)
    {
        if(GetLastError() == 299)
        {
            cout << "ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Any contribution and knowledge you can offer is deeply appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you have a 32 bit process and a 64 bit target?

Comment: Bare with me here because I really don't know much about how memory works, but I don't know the difference.

Comment: @DavidLeon: what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code in the first place?

Comment: I was curious about how decompilation works and such so I'm testing this out on some screen capturing software I made.

Comment: To simply read another process's compiled code, you don't need to use `VirtualAllocEx()` and `VirtualProtectEx()` at all. Simply allocate a local buffer big enough to receive the code, and then `ReadProcessMemory()` into that buffer. Code can be large, so you will likely have to read it in chunks. As for the base address of the code, you will have to read and parse the remote process's PE header to discover where the code is located in memory. Then you can disassemble it manually as needed.

Comment: Your buffer is not initialized `void *buffer;`, that's why you get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I see some issues with your code.

1. Bad error handling.  If an error happens, you log it, but keep going forward with bad data.  If an error happens, STOP.  And you are misusing `GetLastError()`.
2. You are passing the wrong base addess to `VirtualProtectEx()`.  `&baseAddr` neds to be `baseAddr` instead.  Also, you are allocating and protecting the memory with `EXECUTE` permissions, which you should not be using unless you intend to store executable code in the memory (which this code is not doing).
3. You are using `sizeof(DWORD)` to set protection flags on the remote memory, but you are using `sizeof(SIZE_T)` to read the memory.  `DWORD` is a fixed 32 bits in size, but `SIZE_T` is 32 or 64 bits, depending on the platform you are compiling for.  Change `SIZE_T` to `DWORD` to match the rest of your code.
4. You are not allocating any memory in the calling process for `ReadProcessMemory()` to write to.  Change `void *buffer;` to `DWORD buffer;`.

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD dwError;

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, (DWORD)7312);
    if (hProc == NULL)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "OpenProcess has failed. Error: " << dwError << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE token;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &token))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "OpenProcessToken has failed. Error: " << dwError << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    void *baseAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 500, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (baseAddr == NULL)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "VirtualAllocEx has failed. Error: " << dwError << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Base Address: " << baseAddr << endl;

    DWORD prevProt;
    if (!VirtualProtectEx(hProc, baseAddr, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READWRITE, &prevProt))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "VirtualAllocEx has failed. Error: ";
        if (dwError == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
        {
            cout << "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER";
        }
        else if (dwError == ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS)
        {
            cout << "ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << dwError;
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD buffer;
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, &buffer, sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "ReadProcessMemory has failed. Error: ";
        if (dwError == ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY)
        {
            cout << "ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << dwError;
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Value: " << buffer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Some more issues:

5. You are *reserving* memory in the remote process, but you are not *committing* physical storage for that memory, and you are not writing anything into the memory before reading from it.  Reading reserved uncommitted memory is not very useful, and is the likely culprit of your error:

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4457745/65863

   > `ReadProcessMemory` would return FALSE and `GetLastError` would return `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` **when the copy hits a page fault**.

   [Working Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc441804.aspx)

   > When a process references pageable memory that is not currently in its working set, **a page fault occurs**.
6. You are not using the token returned by `OpenProcessToken()`, so that call is useless.
7. You are protecting the remote memory with `VirtualProtectEx()` using the same protection flags you specified when allocating the memory.  So this call is useless, too.

Comment: I did all the stuff you said and it still says `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4457745/65863: "*ReadProcessMemory would return FALSE and GetLastError would return ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY when the copy hits a page fault.*"

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&buffer` is wrong - `ReadProcessMemory` won't allocate buffer for you, it will write on the buffer you provide. You need to allocate memory, and pass that buffer to `ReadProcessMemory`. Possible approach:

```
void *buffer = new BYTE[512];
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, buffer, sizeof(SIZE_T), NULL);
```

Comment: Still returning `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` but thank you for correcting me.