# Why does my ReadProcessMemory() not work? (C#)

Tags: c#, memory, ram

I have the following Code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ProcessMemoryReaderLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ProcessMemoryReader is a class that enables direct reading a process memory
    /// </summary>
    class ProcessMemoryReaderApi
    {
        ///////
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle,
            UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

        private static uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
        private static uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
        private static uint TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
        private static uint TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        private static uint TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
        private static uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
        private static uint TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
        private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
        private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
        private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
        private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
        private static uint TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
        private static uint TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
            TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName,
            out LUID lpLuid);

        public const string SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME = "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege";

        public const string SE_AUDIT_NAME = "SeAuditPrivilege";

        public const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";

        public const string SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME = "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege";

        public const string SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME = "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege";

        public const string SE_CREATE_PAGEFILE_NAME = "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege";

        public const string SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_NAME = "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege";

        public const string SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_NAME = "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege";

        public const string SE_CREATE_TOKEN_NAME = "SeCreateTokenPrivilege";

        public const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";

        public const string SE_ENABLE_DELEGATION_NAME = "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege";

        public const string SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME = "SeImpersonatePrivilege";

        public const string SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME = "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege";

        public const string SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME = "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege";

        public const string SE_INC_WORKING_SET_NAME = "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege";

        public const string SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME = "SeLoadDriverPrivilege";

        public const string SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME = "SeLockMemoryPrivilege";

        public const string SE_MACHINE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "SeMachineAccountPrivilege";

        public const string SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME = "SeManageVolumePrivilege";

        public const string SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME = "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege";

        public const string SE_RELABEL_NAME = "SeRelabelPrivilege";

        public const string SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege";

        public const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";

        public const string SE_SECURITY_NAME = "SeSecurityPrivilege";

        public const string SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeShutdownPrivilege";

        public const string SE_SYNC_AGENT_NAME = "SeSyncAgentPrivilege";

        public const string SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege";

        public const string SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_NAME = "SeSystemProfilePrivilege";

        public const string SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME = "SeSystemtimePrivilege";

        public const string SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME = "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege";

        public const string SE_TCB_NAME = "SeTcbPrivilege";

        public const string SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME = "SeTimeZonePrivilege";

        public const string SE_TRUSTED_CREDMAN_ACCESS_NAME = "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege";

        public const string SE_UNDOCK_NAME = "SeUndockPrivilege";

        public const string SE_UNSOLICITED_INPUT_NAME = "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege";

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public UInt32 LowPart;
            public Int32 HighPart;
        }



        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT = 0x00000001;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED = 0x00000004;
        public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS = 0x80000000;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        {
            public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
            public LUID Luid;
            public UInt32 Attributes;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public LUID Luid;
            public UInt32 Attributes;
        }

        // Use this signature if you do not want the previous state
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool DisableAllPrivileges,
           ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState,
           UInt32 Zero,
           IntPtr Null1,
           IntPtr Null2);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        // constants information can be found in <winnt.h> 
        [Flags]
        public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VMOperation = 0x00000008,
            VMRead = 0x00000010,
            VMWrite = 0x00000020,
            DupHandle = 0x00000040,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hProcess);

        public static byte[] ReadMemory(Process process, int address, int numOfBytes, out int bytesRead)
        {

            IntPtr hProc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[numOfBytes];
            IntPtr newaddress = new IntPtr(address);
            newaddress = IntPtr.Add(newaddress, 0x558);
            ReadProcessMemory(hProc, newaddress, buffer, numOfBytes, out bytesRead);

            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("process" + hProc);
            Console.WriteLine("baseadres:" + newaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Bytesread:" + bytesRead);
            return buffer;
        }
        static int Main()
        {
            //////////////
            IntPtr hToken;
            LUID luidSEDebugNameValue;
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkpPrivileges;

            if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, out hToken))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken() failed, error = {0} . SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return 0 ;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken() successfully");
            }

            if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_DEBUG_NAME, out luidSEDebugNameValue))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed, error = {0} .SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                CloseHandle(hToken);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() successfully");
            }

            tkpPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tkpPrivileges.Luid = luidSEDebugNameValue;
            tkpPrivileges.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, ref tkpPrivileges, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed, error = {0} .SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SeDebugPrivilege is now available");
            }
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            Console.ReadLine();
            ///////////////
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("IWBTO").FirstOrDefault();
            int address = 0x002D2FA8;
           // int offset1 = 0x558;

            int bytesRead;

            byte[] pointer = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadMemory(process, address, 4, out bytesRead);

            //address = bytesRead + offset1;

            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
        }
   }
```

The Code is Supposed to look up a Value in the memory of the Proccess IWBTO, with the BaseAdress of 0x002D2FA8 and an offset of 0x558.
 But the function always returns 0, meaning it failed. This is what i got in the Debug Window:

- 299
- process1036
- baseadres:2962688
- Bytesread:0

Comment: 299 is `"ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY 299 (0x12B) Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed."` What is the purpose of the offset by `0x558`? Also, `lpNumberOfBytesRead` should be an `IntPtr`.

Comment: As a side note may I suggest wonderful c# library for mremory related operations https://github.com/ZenLulz/MemorySharp

Comment: @Rotem Can you tell me what i should write there exactly ? The offset is needed, or else i will point to the wrong address.the baseaddress and offset i found out in cheatengine.

Comment: @battler11, do you have needed rights? Your process must have [PROCESS_VM_READ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx) right

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan  IntPtr hProc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id); shouldnt this line give me the rights?

Comment: @battler11, no, it just open process and return its handle. Try to set [SeDebugPrivilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx) before OpenProcess. Here is [P/Invoke for C#](http://hintdesk.com/Web/Source/Program.cs)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan I edited my code according to the example and  all debug messages say that i now have the rights, but it still gives me a 299 error.

Comment: @battler11, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34648230/5794617](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34648230/5794617) could be helpful

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan sadly not, also the dude who asked the question in your link couldnt get it to work.

Comment: @serhiyb i looked it up and found that it only supported 32bit, any 64bit alternative?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** Now print out memory info.
[Working code at fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ssnvV7). Process are **x64**. One process generate Guid and get its byte representation and print out its address, another read data from that process at that address. For correctness checking do comparison of read Guid.
Test example:
[image: Test example]
Code:

```
namespace ReadProcessMemoryExample
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using WinApi;

    public class Program
    {
        public static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Memory writer generate Guid and write it buffer
            // Memory reader read it 
            if (args != null && args.Contains("-writer"))
            {
                MemoryWriter();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MemoryReader();
            }
        }
        private static void MemoryReader()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mode: Reader");

            if (!EnablePrivelege())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't enable privilegs. Exiting...");
                return;
            }
            Console.Write("Enter generated Guid from writer for correctess checking: ");
            Guid validGuid = Guid.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter process id: ");
            int procId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter memory reading addr in hex(example, 0x24B004446D0): ");
            string strHex = Console.ReadLine().Replace("0x", "");
            long addrToRead = long.Parse(strHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

            IntPtr hProc = IntPtr.Zero, hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            hProc = WinApiWrapper.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, procId);
            try
            {
                if (!WinApiWrapper.OpenProcessToken(hProc, (uint)TokenAccess.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, out hToken))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken failed with error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return;
                }
                IntPtr pAddr = new IntPtr(addrToRead);
                MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memInfo;
                if (0 == WinApiWrapper.VirtualQueryEx(hProc, pAddr, out memInfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)))){
                    Console.WriteLine("VirtualQueryEx failed with error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Memory info: ");
                PrintMemInfo(memInfo);
                Console.WriteLine();

                // Guid length is 16 bytes!
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
                IntPtr readBytesPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!WinApiWrapper.ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pAddr, buffer, buffer.Length, out readBytesPtr))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ReadProcessMemory failed with error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return;
                }
                long readBytes = readBytesPtr.ToInt64();
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from 0x{1:X}", readBytesPtr.ToInt64(), pAddr.ToInt64());
                Console.Write("Buffer data is: ");
                ShowBuffer(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine();

                Guid guid = new Guid(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Buffer as Guid: {0}", guid);
                if (validGuid == guid)
                    Console.WriteLine("Read memory is OK!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Read memory failed!");

                Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to quit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                    WinApiWrapper.CloseHandle(hToken);
                if (hProc != IntPtr.Zero)
                    WinApiWrapper.CloseHandle(hProc);
            }
        }
        private static unsafe void MemoryWriter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mode: Writer");

            // Print out current ProcessId. We use it reader!
            Console.WriteLine("Process Id: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            // Generate some random bytes
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

            Console.WriteLine("Generated new Guid: {0}", guid);
            byte[] buffer = guid.ToByteArray();
            Console.Write("Guid as byte array: ");
            ShowBuffer(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine();
            fixed (byte* p = buffer)
            {
                IntPtr bufAddr = new IntPtr((void*)(p));
                // Print out buffer address. We use it in reader!
                Console.WriteLine("Buffer address: 0x{0:X}", bufAddr.ToInt64());
                // Don't press Enter until reader read the memory!
                Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to quit(Don't press Enter until reader read the memory!)");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Buffer address: 0x{0:X}", bufAddr.ToInt64());
            }
        }
        private static void PrintMemInfo(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BaseAddress: 0x{0:X}", memInfo.BaseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("AllocationBase: 0x{0:X}", memInfo.AllocationBase.ToInt64());
            Console.WriteLine("AllocationProtect: {0}", (AllocationProtect)memInfo.AllocationProtect);
            Console.WriteLine("RegionSize: {0}", memInfo.RegionSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Protect: {0}", (AllocationProtect)memInfo.Protect);
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", (MemState)memInfo.State);
            Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", (MemType)memInfo.Type);
        }
        private static void ShowBuffer(byte[] buffer)
        {
            foreach (var b in buffer)
                Console.Write("{0:x2} ", b);
        }
        private static bool EnablePrivelege()
        {
            IntPtr hToken;
            LUID luidSEDebugNameValue;
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkpPrivileges;

            if (!WinApiWrapper.OpenProcessToken(WinApiWrapper.GetCurrentProcess(), (uint)TokenAccess.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | (uint)TokenAccess.TOKEN_QUERY, out hToken))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken() failed, error = {0} . SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken() successfully");
            }

            if (!WinApiWrapper.LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SePrivilegeNames.SE_DEBUG_NAME, out luidSEDebugNameValue))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed, error = {0} .SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                WinApiWrapper.CloseHandle(hToken);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() successfully");
            }

            tkpPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tkpPrivileges.Luid = luidSEDebugNameValue;
            tkpPrivileges.Attributes = (uint)SePrivilege.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            bool isOk = true;
            if (!WinApiWrapper.AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, ref tkpPrivileges, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed, error = {0} .SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                isOk = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SeDebugPrivilege is now available");
            }
            WinApiWrapper.CloseHandle(hToken);
            return isOk;
        }

    }
}
namespace WinApi
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public enum MemState : uint
    {
        MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000,
        MEM_FREE = 0x10000,
        MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000
    }
    public enum MemType : uint
    {
        MEM_IMAGE = 0x1000000,
        MEM_MAPPED = 0x40000,
        MEM_PRIVATE = 0x20000
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum AllocationProtect : uint
    {
        PAGE_EXECUTE = 0x00000010,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READ = 0x00000020,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x00000040,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY = 0x00000080,
        PAGE_NOACCESS = 0x00000001,
        PAGE_READONLY = 0x00000002,
        PAGE_READWRITE = 0x00000004,
        PAGE_WRITECOPY = 0x00000008,
        PAGE_GUARD = 0x00000100,
        PAGE_NOCACHE = 0x00000200,
        PAGE_WRITECOMBINE = 0x00000400
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr BaseAddress;
        public IntPtr AllocationBase;
        public uint AllocationProtect;
        public IntPtr RegionSize;
        public uint State;
        public uint Protect;
        public uint Type;
    }
    public class SePrivilegeNames
    {
        public const string SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME = "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege";
        public const string SE_AUDIT_NAME = "SeAuditPrivilege";
        public const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";
        public const string SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME = "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege";
        public const string SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME = "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege";
        public const string SE_CREATE_PAGEFILE_NAME = "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege";
        public const string SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_NAME = "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege";
        public const string SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_NAME = "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege";
        public const string SE_CREATE_TOKEN_NAME = "SeCreateTokenPrivilege";
        public const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";
        public const string SE_ENABLE_DELEGATION_NAME = "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege";
        public const string SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME = "SeImpersonatePrivilege";
        public const string SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME = "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege";
        public const string SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME = "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege";
        public const string SE_INC_WORKING_SET_NAME = "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege";
        public const string SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME = "SeLoadDriverPrivilege";
        public const string SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME = "SeLockMemoryPrivilege";
        public const string SE_MACHINE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "SeMachineAccountPrivilege";
        public const string SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME = "SeManageVolumePrivilege";
        public const string SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME = "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege";
        public const string SE_RELABEL_NAME = "SeRelabelPrivilege";
        public const string SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege";
        public const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";
        public const string SE_SECURITY_NAME = "SeSecurityPrivilege";
        public const string SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeShutdownPrivilege";
        public const string SE_SYNC_AGENT_NAME = "SeSyncAgentPrivilege";
        public const string SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege";
        public const string SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_NAME = "SeSystemProfilePrivilege";
        public const string SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME = "SeSystemtimePrivilege";
        public const string SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME = "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege";
        public const string SE_TCB_NAME = "SeTcbPrivilege";
        public const string SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME = "SeTimeZonePrivilege";
        public const string SE_TRUSTED_CREDMAN_ACCESS_NAME = "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege";
        public const string SE_UNDOCK_NAME = "SeUndockPrivilege";
        public const string SE_UNSOLICITED_INPUT_NAME = "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege";
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum SePrivilege : uint
    {
        SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT = 0x00000001,
        SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002,
        SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED = 0x00000004,
        SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS = 0x80000000,
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum TokenAccess : uint
    {
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000,
        TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001,
        TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002,
        TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004,
        TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008,
        TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010,
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020,
        TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040,
        TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080,
        TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100,
        TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY),
        TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
            TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID)
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
        VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
        VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
        DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
        CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
        SetQuota = 0x00000100,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        public UInt32 LowPart;
        public Int32 HighPart;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }
    class WinApiWrapper
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName, out LUID lpLuid);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

        // Use this signature if you do not want the previous state
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, bool DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, UInt32 Zero, IntPtr Null1, IntPtr Null2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the version of your OS? Try to start command prompt with admin rights

Comment: Also you **must not close** writer app until reader read the memory

Comment: I have windows 10. I am closing nothing until i get the error message, also what writer app? i only have this one application. Starting as Admin changes nothing.

Comment: If you look the code, you can see calling 2 methods in main: MemoryWriter or MemoryReader. It will call these methods depends on passed args. If you pass '-writer', it will call MemoryWriter. otherwise it MemoryReader. We need to start 2 instances of this app to show how ReadProcessMemory works. Here is the [gif of entire process](http://gph.is/2b8RI2Z), [direct link](http://i.giphy.com/l2Sq3YLdvtZlWGRQA.gif)